# Phusion Passenger error 'Unknown key(s): through'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

My rails application runs fine on my local testing server, but when I deploy to my production (Passenger) server, I get the following error:

```
Error message:
  Unknown key(s): through

Exception class:
  ArgumentError
```

Why might this be happening? The code can't be inherently flawed, since everything works fine on the development server. The offending piece of code is very simple:

```
class PageEvent < Event
   belongs_to :page, :through => :calendar
end
```

where

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar, :polymorphic => true
end
```

and

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :calendar, :as => :calendar, :class_name => "SpecialEvent"
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say what is happening that it appears to be working in dev, but there is no `belongs_to :through`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Comment: Yeah… code works fine without it. I wonder why it still worked in development.